# UBUNTU-xinput DONT save settings after restart, unplug, etc

Tags: ubuntu, settings, mouse, device, xinput

Well, thing is that I have an *Abyssus Razer* that works perfectly on *MATE*, **but** on *Debian*, *Elementary*, *OpenSUSE*, and others the **DEFAULT** setting is super slow.

I solved the thing with **XINPUT**. It's even better than the original software, you can take control of it all.

But, when I **restart**, re-log, or something like that, the **settings** I did are reseted too.

*Once, after tons of time doing it, it saved by itself.* But I had to reinstall my OS and now *every time I turn on my computer* I have to do:

```
xinput set-prop 8 "libinput Accel Profile Enabled" 0, 1
xinput set-prop 8 "libinput Accel Speed" 0.500
```

That is a default speed.

+: "su" or "sudo" doesn't solve the problem

Hope you can help me, cause I have been looking around but couldn't find information about "saving xinput settings".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with "alias"

```
alias mouse="xinput set-prop 8 279 0.500 && xinput set-prop 8 282 0, 1"
```

Never knew you can do this tricks...

Well, for now I'm happy with this solution so I close it, and hope can help someone my way of making it work.

be safe